# Erro: Incorrect syntax near 'End' no Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Esse código aqui insiste em dizer que existe um erro de syntax, mas eu não consegui identificar oque  exatamente está errado. Já tentei tirar o "go", o "end", porém, continua dizendo erro de syntax.

```
DECLARE @NumFix tinyint, @NumVar tinyint

Set @NumFix = 1
While @NumFix <= 10
    
Begin
     Set @NumVar = 1
     Print 'Tabuada do: ' + Convert (char(6), @NumFix)
     While @NumVar <= 10
      Begin 
       Print Convert (char(6), @NumFix) + ' x ' + Convert (char(6), @NumVar) + ' = ' + Convert (char(6), (@NumFix * @NumVar))
       Set @NumVar = @NumVar + 1

End
Set @Numfix = @NumFix + 1
Go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o GO deve ser usado fora do bloco de instruções do loop. Porque o GO é um separador do lote e é usado para indicar o final de um lote de instruções. Além disso, após o While você dá Begin mas não acaba por fechar.

```
DECLARE @NumFix tinyint, @NumVar tinyint

Set @NumFix = 1
While @NumFix <= 10

Begin
     Set @NumVar = 1
     Print 'Tabuada do: ' + Convert (char(6), @NumFix)
     While @NumVar <= 10
      Begin 
       Print Convert (char(6), @NumFix) + ' x ' + Convert (char(6), @NumVar) + ' = ' + Convert (char(6), (@NumFix * @NumVar))
       Set @NumVar = @NumVar + 1
      End
Set @Numfix = @NumFix + 1
End
```

Comment: Obrigado João!!